# Not able to debug C program in code blocks

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks

Not able to debug C program in code blocks (ver 17.12) in windows10. Search  the other answers also, but none of them seem to help.

I have "-g" option enabled in the compiler settings. When put a break point and run F8. Program execution did not stop at the break point. Can someone help what I'm missing here.

```
Adding file: C:\c-progs\C\CProject\bin\Debug\CProject.exe
Changing directory to: C:/c-progs/C/CProject/.
Set variable: PATH=.;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Python27;C:\Users\quizzeria\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
Starting debugger: C:\c-progs\C\CProject\bin\Debug\CProject.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args C:/c-progs/C/CProject/bin/Debug/CProject.exe
done
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: Tell us the compiler debugger that you used.

Comment: The posted output is not setting any 'break' statement.  Please post the source code and the setting of the break statement

Comment: It looks kind of like you've configured your program as its own debugger. That can't work. What are your debugger settings in codeblocks?

Comment: @melpomene You're right. I realised the mistake. It works fine when I have "gdb.exe" path. "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gdb32.exe"